# Get Site columns: Unauthorized operation in Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, get-site-columns

I'm a newby to both powershell scripting and Sharepoint. I am trying to write the following powershell script that will get all site columns from my Sharepoint 2010 site and put them in a csv file.

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$url = <My Site URL>
$fileName = "<MyDirectory>\siteColumns.csv"
"Column Title `t Site Column ID `t InternalName `t StaticName `t MaxLength `t Description `t Group `t TypeShortDescription " | out-file $fileName

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.rootweb.Fields
echo "Generation File..."
ForEach ($id in $web)
{
    "$($id.Title) `t $($id.Id) `t $($id.InternalName) `t $($id.StaticName) `t $($id.MaxLength)/$($id.MaxLength) `t $($id.Description) `t $($id.Group) `t $($id.TypeShortDescription) " | Out-File $fileName -Append
}
$site.Dispose()
```

The script runs fine until it reaches the ForEach loop. When it reaches this point I am getting the following error:

```
The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Attempted to perfo
rm an unauthorized operation.".
At C:\Users\IP2560_a\Documents\PSScripts\GetSiteColumns.ps1:9 char:8
+ ForEach <<<<  ($id in $web)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

I am running in a shell that has Administrator error. Are there any permissions I need to set up in Sharepoint itself or something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint farm admin account not granted rights for site collections automatically, try to add the account to your site collection owners group(I tested your script, working fine).

Update:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Lee_MSFT I am told I am already an administrator. Where do i go to check this? Is it in Security > Users > Manage the farm adminstrators group? Or Application Management > Change Site Collection Administrators? Should I be on both those lists?

Comment: Go to site collection and try to add the user to Site Settings->Site permissions : site Owners  group.

Comment: Hmm. I seem to get access denied when I try to hit the url now. It looks like there is something else going on here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could add the user as administrator by user policy in farm admin center if you can't access site collection, check the update screenshot.

Comment: Finally got this solved. Even though I was set up as a site administrator I wasn't able to gain access. When I was removed and then re added as an administrator it worked. Thanks for your assistance Lee.